# Can a JavaScript loop, upon the second iteration, iterate from the result of the prior iteration?

Tags: javascript, loops

I just joined Stack Overflow and this is my first post so please do not hesitate to let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

I was presented with a challenge to create a function that accepts a string and calls another given function which swaps indices until the string is returned backwards.

I have gotten as far as below:

```js
//given function
function swap(str, first, last){
    str = str.split('');
    let firstIndex = str[first];    
    str[first] = str[last];
    str[last] = firstIndex;
    str = str.join("").toString()
    return str;
}

//my function
let word = "Hello"
function reverseSwap(str) {
  let result = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length/2; i++) {
  result += swap(str, i, str.length -1 - i);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(reverseSwap(word))
```

This however returns "oellHHlleoHello", because each iteration swaps indices from the original string then concatenates. Is it possible, upon the second iteration, to have the loop iterate from the result of the prior iteration so the following occurs?:

result of first iteration: swap(word, 0, 4) which returns "oellH"
second iteration uses "oellH" instead of "Hello" to swap(1, 3) which returns "olleH"
Then, swap(2,2) which doesn't change anything.

Comment: `let result = ""` -> `let result = str` and `result += swap(str, i, str.length -1 - i);` -> `result = swap(result, i, str.length -1 - i);`

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because

- **Don't += add all new strings** to your result. (This will append each swap string to your result.)
- You have to **manipulate always the "result" string**. (You want to do a swap always on the updated version of the string. Not the original one)

Here is a simple solution:

```js
function swap(str, first, last) {
  str = str.split("");
  let firstIndex = str[first];
  str[first] = str[last];
  str[last] = firstIndex;
  str = str.join("").toString();
  return str;
}

let word = "Hello";

function reverseSwap(str) {
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length / 2; i++) {
    str = swap(str, i, str.length - 1 - i);
  }
  return str;
}
console.log(reverseSwap(word));
```